# Как сделать проверку на ввод запятой?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть обработка нажатия клавиши. Мне нужно по вводу запятой выполнить какой-то код. Но дело в том, что значение "русской запятой" - 191, а "английской" - 188, таким образом если сделать проверку по 188, то я лишусь возможности вводить русскую "б".

```
$('input').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 191 || event.which == 188) //do some actions
});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему! =) Спасибо.

Comment: событие `keypress` Вам не подходит?

Comment: Дело в том, что код не мой и событие использовалось именно keydown, написал выше свое с keypress и все работает)) Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

А если через регуляр var **reg=/\,/gi**;?

```
   <input type="text" value="value" onkeyup="key(this)"  />
    <script>
    function key(elem){

        var reg=/\,/gi;

        elem.value=elem.value.replace(reg,'!');
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(String.fromCharCode(event.which) == ','){
    //do some actions
}
```

Вот только я не понял, каким образом у вас получаются значения 191 и 188...

Comment: @ling при событиях `keydown` и `keyup` в `event.which` содержится KeyCode (код клавиши). при событии keypress в `event.which` содержится CharCode (код символа) Ваш пример будет вести себя адекватно только при событии `keypress`